# Flatten a multi-dimensional array, whilst removing an element from each

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to flatten a multi-dimensional array, whilst also removing an element from each sub-array?

Currently, I am storing two elements per sub-array, like so:

```
Array ( 
    [billing_first_name] => Array ( 
        [0] => Test 
        [1] => 1 
    ) 
    [billing_last_name] => Array ( 
        [0] => Test 
        [1] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

But I need to remove the second sub-element, flattening the array to:

```
Array ( 
    [billing_first_name] => Test 
    [billing_last_name] => Test 
)
```

I had thought that this could be possible through a foreach, but after removing the 2nd element from the sub-array, I'm unsure what route would be most efficient to flatten the array.

```
foreach( $customer_data_new as $key => $value ) {

    unset($customer_data_new[$key][1]);

}
```

If anyone could explain the best option, I would be graatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```
$customer_data_new  = array(
            'billing_first_name' => array(
                '0' =>'Test',
                '1' => 1
            ),
            'billing_last_name' => array(
                '0' =>'Test',
                '1' => 1
            )
        );

$newData = array();
foreach( $customer_data_new as $key => $value ) {
    $newData[$key] = $value[0];    
}
print_r($newData);
```

[Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/WgTtN)

Answer (score 1):

Call `current()` on every subarray.  Dead simple.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/auvfg))

```
var_export(array_map('current', $customer_data_new));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'billing_first_name' => 'Test',
  'billing_last_name' => 'Test',
)
```